# IBAction Open Local HTML File

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I've got a view based application that one is at last just a single WebView ... with a Tabbar with some Icons.
So i need to add a small icon for go back to the localHTML File home.html.

Maybe could someone give me some informations how to handle it without change the view to a new one?

Here is how my other `IBActions` looks like

```
- (IBAction)news_button:(id)sender; {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]]; 
}
```

Other option could be open a Website but not in safari ... like it does at the moment.

Thanks for sharing! :)

Answer (score 0):

With the line above you are opening it in Safari right now.

You can get path to the local file if it is in main bundle catalog with

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"home.html"] retain];
```

So why not use

```
[yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest initWithURL:[NSUrl initWithString:filePath]]];
```

Comment: Should this:
[NSUrl initWithString:filePath]
be this: (uppercase 'rl', and class method):
[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] ?